# How do I get Linux drivers for Epson ES-50 scanner

Tags: drivers, scanner, epson, sane

I got a new Document scanner the Epson ES-50. Epson doesn't provide official Linux drivers. So I was looking into scanners imported by the SANE project.

The ES-50 is listed here: http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html as supported but unmaintained. So If I just install the basic Repos which are provided `sane` `sane-utils` `libsane-common` I end up not being able to use the scanner, although it gets recognized.

```
➜  ~ sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8, product=0x016c [Epson ES-50]) at libusb:001:004
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

But the list provides this unmaintained http://www.sane-project.org/man/sane-epsonds.5.html backend.

My Question now is; How do I install this package to test this out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Epson does provide official Linux drivers for the ES-50 model.

You can find them [here](https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX)

Search by the model name and install the drivers.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clearly enough in this. Although Epson supports Linux with most devices, it does not with the Epson ES-50

Comment: It does with ES-50. If you enter `ES-50` to the search box, you'll get the driver.

Comment: I stand corrected. It works flawlessly. On the official site, they stated to not have drivers. I didn't bother to search in your provided Link. Thanks for your patience